# Old HP nc6120 can't connect to new router

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router, lubuntu

Today I replaced my router with a new one (LevelOne WGR-6013 b/g/n).

I have a smartphone and my notebook that connect just fine.
However, I have an old HP nc6120 (ipw2200 b/g) notebook running Lubuntu 13.10 i386 that keeps throwing me

> Authentication required by wireless network

It used to connect just fine on the old router (a D-Link DIR 601), but now no matter what I try, I can't get it to work. For the record, I've kept the security settings identical: WPA2-PSK/AES, no MAC filtering (for now), b/g/n mixed mode for now but I tried b/g as well, same issue.

I removed the setting, set the SSID broadcast on, Lubuntu finds the network, I fill out the connection settings, no joy: again the popup.
When I pop in the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386 cd, it offers the possibility to connect to a wireless network before installation (so it can download updates as it's installing), but there as well, the password box persists.

In this equation, the *router* is all that changed.
The router logs don't tell me anything. Upgraded to the latest firmware, problem persists. Don't really know what else I could check. Thanks in advance for any advice or similar experiences you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried a different distro to see if the problem is just with ubuntu ? or tried different ways of configuring wireless ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't be the first time that an old wireless interface choked when confronted with joining a newer flavor of 802.11. Even if you disable N on an N-capable 802.11 AP (read: "Wi-Fi router"), it may not perfectly replicate the behavior of a legacy B/G AP. For example, 802.11n required QoS (WMM). Disabling N might not disable WMM, and it might be that your HP nc6120 is choking when it sees the WMM information elements.

To fully diagnose this kind of problem often requires capturing and analyzing 802.11 monitor-mode packet traces (captured on a separate machine) of both a successful and an unsuccessful connection attempt. For example, if the connection works just fine with the old (I'm assuming) B/G only AP, but fails with the new B/G/N AP even when it's in B/G-only mode, we can look to see if the B/G/N AP transmits any WMM information elements. Then, if the configuration UI for your new B/G/N AP lets you disable WMM when N is disabled, you could disable WMM as well and see if the HP nc6120 can connect then. This is just one example. There may be any number of other differences that would become apparent when analyzing the "successful" and "unsuccessful" 802.11 monitor-mode packet traces.

Comment: in the end it's just not worth the trouble. It's incompatible. Period. I'm getting another router.

Comment: @Wim In my opinion, it's the old client that's choking, not the router. It's quite possible that your old client will choke on any semi-modern router. Buy a new client or buy a new wireless card (e.g. USB dongle) for your client.